# Is there a way through XCode or a third party tool to view the UIImage variable image in the console log

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, uiimage

I want to be explicit that I am **not** referring to the quick look feature built into XCode:
[image]

My issue with this approach is that I need to review about 50 images per run, and the action of clicking through each time is going to give me carpal tunnel at this point.

I do not think there is something officially baked into XCode that will provide what I want, so my hope is that there is a third party tool that can handle this. Preferably, something that may place it in the variable in the debug console so that I may view the image.

[image]

Comment: it is possible to add breakpoint and edit it so it can print needed properties.

Comment: @kirander I need to see the image so I can verify that it is being processed properly.  Will update the question to make that more explicit.

Comment: Can you not take each image and export each one to the camera roll and review them after the fact?  Do you need to do it in real-time with debugging?

Comment: I am almost sure, it is not possible to view pictures in debugger window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what I was looking for, but something that XCode does provide is fairly close to what I want.

[image]

1. When a breakpoint is hit, select the variable in the console
2. Click on the eye icon seen below
3. The image window seen here will appear with an anchor to the variable

This is with XCode 8.

The benefit of this approach is that it saves me from having to track to the variable in code, hover over it, and then move the cursor just so such that the window does not close before I can click on the inspection icon.